# Display in table

Tags: php, sql, html, codeigniter

I"ve a table like this

```
global_id | auto_trans | add_drivers |child_seat | booster_seat | day   
- - - - - - - -  - - - - - - - -- -- -  - - - - - - --  - - - - - - - -
   18           2          1             5              2          2
- - - - - -  - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  - - - - - - -  -
   19           5          8             7              6          1 
- - - - - - - -  - - - - - -  - - -  -  - - - - -  - - - - - - - - -  -
   20           2          4             7              9          3
 - - - - - - - - -  -- -  - - - - - -  - - - - - - - -  - - - - - - -  -
```

I want to display the values in a table in the below format

```
 ___________|__1_|_2_ |_3 |
  |         |    |    |   |
auto_trans  | 5  | 2  | 2 |
- - - - -  - - - - -  - - -
add_drivers | 8  | 1  | 4 |
 -- -  - - -  - - - - - --
child_seat  | 7  | 5  | 7 |
 - - -  - - - - - - - - - -
booster_seat| 6  | 2  | 9 |
 - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
```

How to write loop for this?

Comment: Please try formatting your example. I've now read it twice and I still don't get what you're aiming at.

Comment: Are looking to `PIVOT` your table to aggregate the results? Although I'm not sure where the field names "1", "2" & "3" come from in your display format.

Comment: How many rows do you have just three or may have more than or less than 3?

Comment: @Tony is right you need to `Pivot` the result set

Comment: Which database server are you using? That will help people answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *easy* answer? By creating a loop in a loop that'll store the value of a columnname by columnname, instead of what row it is in in the database (see below for an example if you're in a pickle and need this solved ASAP). The **correct** answer, however, is that you probably [need to normalise your database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) a little further. Although the values seem to be related, your request to print them in this way tells me your database might be a little off.

```
<?php
/** Just assuming. */
$results = $db->query( 
    'SELECT auto_trans, add_drivers, child_seat, booster_seat ORDER BY auto_trans' 
)->fetchAll( );

$categorised = array( );
foreach( $results as $result ) {
    foreach( $result as $columname => $value ) {
        if( !array_key_exists( $columnname, $categorised ) ) {
            $categories[$columnname] = array( );
        }
        $categories[$columnname][] = $value;
    }
}

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
foreach( $categories as $category => $values ) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>" . $category . "</th>";
    foreach( $values as $value ) {
        echo "<td>" . $value . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is pivot or crosstab but the actual solution depends on which database you are using.

MS SqlServer 2005 has a PIVOT command to do this but many others do not.

As you are using Php I assume its MySQL och ProstgreSQL

For PostgreSQL check this out: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html

For MySQL it seems to be more difficult , check this: http://mysql.bigresource.com/crosstab-query-Pivot-table-1mjeYKlS.html#WAGYCZsH